# Use string + variable + string on document.write

Tags: javascript

i need to show on a window.open, a document.write with 2 strings and a variable on it, but the problem is that the variable is not showing and in the place of it , it shows : [object window], here is my code, thanks.

```
function showResult() {
    var result = parseInt(valor1 + valor2 + valor3 + valor4 + valor5 +
        valor6 + valor7 + valor8 + valor9 + valor10 + valor11 + valor12 +
        valor13 + valor14 + valor15 + valor16 + valor17 + valor18 +
        valor19 + valor20 + valor21 + valor22 + valor23 + valor24 +
        valor25 + valor26 + valor27 + valor28 + valor29 + valor30 +
        valor31 + valor32 + valor33 + valor34 + valor35 + valor36 +
        valor37 + valor38 + valor39 + valor40 + valor41 + valor42 +
        valor43 + valor44 + valor45);
    if (result >= 0 && result <= 20) {
        result = window.open("", "respuesta1",
            "left=150,top=150,height=300,width=500");
        result.document.write("<b> Su resultado es:</b> " + result +
            " <br> <b> Muy Bajo </b> :  Con esta puntuación debes saber que todavía no conoces suficientemente qué emociones son las que vives, no valoras adecuadamente tus capacidades, que es seguro que las tienes. Son muchas las habilidades que no pones en práctica, y son necesarias para que te sientas más a gusto contigo mismo y las relaciones con la gente sean satisfactorias. Este programa de trabajo te podrá ser de gran ayuda para aumentar tus habilidades de inteligencia emocional."
        );
    }
```

Comment: This hurts my eyes

Comment: `result = window.open()` well if you open a new window that winfow is returned. Why would you try to print it?!

Comment: maybe there is a error in your code which combine 45 variables

Comment: Whatever you are doing, stop. Stop it immediately and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me.
I noticed that you are changing result to a new window, this then takes away the value. Therefore, make a new variable called newResult, give it the value of result, then pass it through and it works. :)

```
var valor1 = 2;
var valor2 = 6;
var valor3 = 10;
function showResult() {

    var result = parseInt(valor1 + valor2 + valor3);
    console.log(result);


    if (result >= 0 && result <= 20) {
        newResult = result;
     result = window.open();

       result.document.write("<b> Su resultado es:</b> " + newResult +
         " <br> <b> Muy Bajo </b> :  Con esta puntuación debes saber que"
      );
   }
}


showResult();
```